# Can we use single thread to consume multiple disruptor?

Tags: disruptor-pattern

I have different data coming from different source (multicast, tcp). 
I'm intending to use different Disruptor to manage each type of data individually while I would like to consume all these data by a single thread.

Is such model Disruptor designed for?
If so, the Disruptor constructor comes with Executor / ThreadFactory which implies the data inside should be managed by thread pool. How can we share the same thread to multiple disruptor?

Comment: Can you please specify what is the purpose of single thread processing? Maybe you can use a single ring buffer in the end of the chain and single event handler. It should simulate a single thread behavior and process events one by one. Use work handler if you want to handle events in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

The disruptor library probably won't do that without your effort; I'm not sure what the entire API looks like. There is an api on the ring buffer to get(sequence) and get cursor, at the very least.

But if you understood the pattern, obviously the consumer thread isn't blocked in any API, so a custom implementation could easily poll various ring buffers, especially instead of spinning a busy-wait loop.

However, you might loose some of the cpu cache locality by jumping from one task+memory to another.